How to make a git branch the descendant of an other without changing its content?
I have two branches, 2 and 4:
2c              <- top of branch 2
|
2b
|
2a              <- root branch 2

and
4c             <- top of branch 4
|
4b
|
4a              <- root branch 4

The problem is:
Branch 4 root was actually derived from the top of branch 2 but this was done outside of git.
I would like to reflect that in git, by chaining these 2 branches, so that we can easily identify the differences between 2c and 4a, and also so that the merge of an other third branch that had similar changes would be easier for the merge algorithms.
The result should look like this:
4c             <- top of branch 4
|
4b
|
4a              <- root branch 4
| <================================== new connection between the two branches
2c              <- top of branch 2
|
2b
|
2a              <- root branch 2

After much reading about rebasing and changing a commit's parent, I used the following approach, which doesn't seem optimal:
    cd dev/project      # work locally, within the repo top folder: project
    git checkout 2
    git checkout -b 4L  # temporary branch to perform the link between the branches, based on the top of branch 2 
    git checkout 4
    git checkout 4a     #  retrieve the root of branch 4 in the working directory before to copy it
    cp -r . ../project-copy-4a  # save the work directory for later use

    git checkout -b 4L # return to temporary branch
    rm -rf *           # clean the working directory
    cp -r ../project-copy-4a/* ./  # incorporate the 4a content to simulate the developer     changes from status 2c
    git rm . ; git add .           # make sure to include the new files in git before commit
    git commit -m "connect branches 2 and 4"

I have now this status:
4La     (content equal to 4a)
|
2c              <- top of branch 2
|
2b
|
2a              <- root branch 2

In order to connect the branches, I will now rebase the branch 4 on the branch 4L , which top content is equal to the root of branch 4, hence not changing the contents in any of the branch 4 commits:
    git checkout 4  # move to branch 4
    git rebase 4L   # rebase it on branch 2, through branch 4L

I now have the target status (where 4x' could be a new commit hash from rebase but its content is equal to these of 4x):
4c '            <- top of branch 4
|
4b'
|
(4a')              <- root branch 4 (not sure git keeps this commit as it contains no changes)
|
4La
| <================================== new connection between the two branches
2c              <- top of branch 2
|
2b
|
2a              <- root branch 2


What would be a better procedure to achieve this in pure git commands, without resorting to file system commands like cp -r which can be heavy and risky, for example due to variations between the file system tree and the git files tree ?

If you have a small number of files, just paste them on top of the original branch and then commit.

If the changes to branch 4 were "done outside of git", what are 4a, 4b, and 4c?  In the diagrams above, I would expect those to be the oid of respective commits in git, but if that is the case then what does "outside of git" mean?

@TimBiegeleisen there are about 50k files ... Including hidden .xyz files, which makes teh fiel system commands cp -r and rm -r really tricky, as they include .. folder, .git folder etc ...

@WilliamPursell the modifications done outside of git were from the 2c state to the 4a state.

@WilliamPursell  to better answer to your diagram and oid question, 4a - 4c could be read as the commit ids. What I'm really trying to achieve, in other words,  is to put one branch 4 history as the continuation of the branch 2 history, without changing the content of each stage in either branch.

If 4a - 4c are the oids of commits in git, then what do you mean by "outside of git"?  If you have commits of the changes, then those commits exist in git and the changes were not made "outside of git".

@WilliamPursell I mean by 'outside of git' that the transition from 2c to 4a was performed outside of git. In opposite, 2b-2c and 4a-4b are transitions which are recorded inside of git history. I need to add in git the transition from 2c-4a . Without modifying the 4a state of the history.

@kitatech how are your two branches connected at the moment? Do they share a common commit or do you have 2 root commits in your repository?

@knittl they are disconnected, I have 2 root commits

I think you want to graft your history to have Git pretend that the parent of 4a is 2c:
git replace --graft 4a 2c

Then git filter-branch or git filter-repo to make your graft(s) permanent. This will rewrite your commits and changes their commit hashes; there's no way of avoiding that.
This answer explains how to persist the grafted history. Replace the --all parameter with the commit range that you want to rewrite (e.g. 4a'..4c').

The alternative is to create your commit objects manually from the existing trees:
git checkout 2c
id=$(git commit-tree -m 'commit message' -p 2c 4a^{tree})
id=$(git commit-tree -m 'commit message' -p "$id" 4b^{tree})
…
git merge --ff-only "$id"

The resulting history of both approaches is the same (but the commit-tree approach will use different author and committer dates, unless you manually take care of that).

Your answer led me to You can graft one history onto the other by "replacing" the earliest commit in the new line with the latest commit on the older one which is a much better formulation of my problem. While I need now to learn git commit-tree and replace , the solution looks promising.

As I favor not rewriting the full history of hundreds of commits, I am trying to confirm the alternative. However I do not see the resulting chain. Is it 4c-4b-4b'-4a'-2c-2b-2a (4a' is id1, 4b' is id2) ? For clarity, can you please edit the answer with a graph of the resulting chain of commits from the alternative ? How about the commit from the merge (if any?), where does it fit in the chain  ?

@kitatech you don't need to rewrite all of your history, only the grafted commit and its descendents. Hundreds of commits is peanats. The chain of commits is 2a-2b-2c-4a'-4b'-4c' for both approaches – there aren't any merges.

By merge I refer to this final command: git merge --ff-only "$id" . So from your above comment there aren't any merges I derive that it will adjust all the downstream commits 4a'...4c', but should never face any conflicts while doing so, correct ?

@kitatech merge --ff-only does not create a merge commit, it only fast-forwards your branch. The new commits are created with commit-tree. No commits will be adjusted by running merge --ff-only, only the current branch will be fast-forwarded to the commit with hash "$id". But I wouldn't advise this alternative approach, but recommend the replace/graft-based approach followed by filter-branch/filter-repo.

I am still a bit surprised that every downstream commit (4a'...4c') has to be touched if there is one long upstream chain of commits (e.g. 4b'..4c') which has the exact same content in every commit as before (4b..4c). I fail to see the git logics why these changes are needed if this whole subchain is the same.

OK, so if I go the replace/filter-branch route, does the git filter-branch command in the first solution require parameters, or not at all ?

@kitatech because the subchain is not the same. You want the parent of commit 4a to change, but commits in Git are immutable and can never change. Therefore, you need to create a new commit 4a' with the updated parent. 4b still points to parent 4a (which in turn doesn't have a parent, it's a root commit), so you need to create a new commit 4b' with updated parent 4a'. Now 4c points to an outdated parent – rinse and repeat. Immutable commits and commit ids (hashes) based on the full commit content (including parent ids) is one of the fundamental concepts behind Git's design.

Cool, I missed that "immutable" part, I thought I read we could add/replace parents  of commits.

@kitatech no, you can't. You can only create new commits which are similar to the existing commits and then forget about the existing commits, never touching them again. "Replacing" a single commit means that all descendant commits need to be "replaced" by updated versions of themselves too.
