Smashing two git repos (separated chronologically) back together
My research group took our Git Repo, downloaded the files, uploaded them to a new Git Repo (erasing all history in the progress), and then kept working off the new repo using Git. It ruined the git blame and many other convenient features of version control—in addition to eliminating git history, we lost issue boards and discussions associated with the GitHub repository. Is there a way to smash the repos back together to make the version control history continuous?

What do you mean with "made a copy" exactly? Copying a Git repository doesn't remove the fact that it's a Git repository.

In addition to what is meant by "made a copy", we may also need to know what "It ruined the git blame and many other convenient features of version control." means. We need to know how the copy was made and then what happened after that? (Were new commits made in Git or was the source saved some other way?)

They downloaded the repository files and then uploaded them again to a new hit repository, destroying git history in the process. The new commits were still made in Git, but on a new repository. Have edited for clarity, thank you.

do you know the exact commit they copied from the original repository ?

I think you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78320459/how-to-make-a-git-branch-the-descendant-of-an-other-without-changing-its-content/78320586#78320586 – you can easily fetch commits of both remotes into a single repo, graft, apply grafts, push to your "final" repo. (another similar q&a: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4164767/112968)
